# Airflow and data transfer between operators

Tags: airflow

I'm new to airflow and have a question about Airflow and its processors.
When a processor produces an output, how this output is moved in input to the next processor ? 
There is a software called nifi which stores intermediate outputs into flowfiles, afaik there is nothing like this in airflow.
So how does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Airflow uses [Xcoms](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) to pass data between operators.

If the flow is operator A -> operator B, then operator A must "push" a value to xcom, and operator B must "pull" this value from A if it wants to read it.

Any operators downstream from A have access to any values A pushed to Xcom via:

```py
value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a', key='key_name')
```

And operator A would push this value like this:

```py
context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key_name,value,context['execution_date'])
```

Comment: Just another ( simple ?) question : where xcom stores data ?

Comment: in the airflow DB xcom table

Comment: Could it be used to share the result of queries to other task, if so how can I do it? Where can I find more examples of this, I find the framework a bit messy

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto consider posting a more detailed version of this question as a new question. I think the answer is "yes", but more information is necessary to provide a good answer.

Comment: Is there is any way to know the `task_ids`  that the current task is dependent on. For example [a,b] >> c. If I'm doing data1 = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='a', key='key_name') and data2 = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='b', key='key_name') in c, then I need to know about the dependencies. It there any way to know about a,b in c ?

Comment: So is the xcom key:val pair stored in the context['task_instance'] object? I'm confused why xcom push and pull functions seem to be methods of the context['task_instance'] object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are referring to the GenericTransfer operator, that helps moving data between data soruces?

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/generic_transfer.py

Comment: I think they are asking how to pass data from one operator into another, rather than how to get data from one location through an operator into another location.