# Transfer Data between airflow custom operators

Tags: python, airflow

I am creating my own custom operators in airflow and would like to use the output of one operator as an input of another operator. Currently the way I am doing is storing the output in s3 and read them from s3 in the next operator which seems an in efficient way. I came across a following post [Airflow and data transfer between operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762087/airflow-and-data-transfer-between-operators][1]) 
but I couldn't understand it quite clear. I'd really appreciate if some one can give me with a good example of data transfer between operator.

```
class SFScoreDataOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, aws_key, aws_secret,
                 model_version='2020-04-v2',
                 *args, **kwargs):
        self.__version__ = model_version
        self.aws_key = aws_key
        self.aws_secret = aws_secret
        super(SFScoreDataOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        SuccessFactorData(aws_key=self.aws_key, aws_secret=self.aws_secret, to_random_shuffle=False).get_data()


class SFScoreGetTrainOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, aws_key, aws_secret,
                 model_version='2020-04-v2',
                 *args, **kwargs):
        self.__version__ = model_version
        self.aws_key = aws_key
        self.aws_secret = aws_secret
        super(SFScoreGetTrainOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        CM = SuccessFactorTrain(aws_key=self.aws_key, aws_secret=self.aws_secret)
        df_to_predict = CM.fetch_predict_data()
        df_train_test = CM.fetch_final_data()
        CM.train_test(final_df_for_train_test=df_train_test, segment_type=None)

class SuccessFactorDataPluginV2(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'success_factor_data_plugin_v2'
    operators = [SFScoreDataOperator]


class SuccessFactorTrainPluginV2(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'success_factor_train_plugin_v2'
    operators = [SFScoreGetTrainOperator]
```

The class method get_data in class SFScoreDataOperator outputs two tables which are inputs from train_test method in SFScoreGetTrainOperator and the train_test method outputs 3 variables which would be the inputs for the next custom operator. Not all outputs are in CSV format so I am unable to write them to s3. I read the XCom documentation but not sure how to implement it so would really appreciate if I can get a push. Thanks!